# Fresh installation of bullet physics engine is not linking properly?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, bulletphysics

Have a relatively new and fresh installation of ubuntu LTS, I followed the instructions found here for generic dynamic library building: http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Installation

Installation appears to go smoothly (no errors or warnings) and afterwards I have all of the necessary files located in /usr/local/include/bullet.  I'm currently attempting to compile a file from the following shell command:

g++ bulletTest.cpp -lGL -lGLU -I /usr/local/include/bullet/

bulletTest.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
int main (void)
{
    btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase;
    return 0;
}
```

This file has nothing to it, but is throwing a plethora of undefined reference errors, such as "/tmp/ccH09wLR.o:(.rodata._ZTV17btTypedConstraint[_ZTV17btTypedConstraint]+0x30): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'"  I cannot find any other complaints on the forums/SO so I believe it must be a problem with my build/installation.  These types of errors occur while attempting both gcc and g++ compilers.

Anybody have an idea?

EDIT: changed my shell command to g++ bulletTest.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision -lBulletSoftBody -lLinearMath -I /usr/local/include/bullet/

It compiles but does not run, error is: error while loading shared libraries: libBulletDynamics.so.2.82: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I believe you need to link with the bullet physics libraries `.a` or `.so` files using a flag like `-lbullet -L/usr/local/lib`

Comment: It says no such library as -lbullet

Comment: Where did you install the libraries `libbullet.so` (shared library) and/or `libbullet.a` (static library)? Have a look.

Comment: there is no "libbullet.so" but a number of sublibraries in /usr/local/lib under names such as "libBulletDynamics.so" and "libBulletDynamics.a"  Should I instead be using "lBulletDynamics"?  EDIT: yeah, okay using the libraries in the form "-lBulletDynamics" worked.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: Yes you need to add the library which contains the symbol `btBroadphaseInterface`. I am not familiar enough with this library to tell you which one. Simplest way to check is to use the `binutils` `strings` command to see where this string occurs.

Answer (score 2):

So it was a lot of little stuff.  Firstly, don't reference "lbullet" reference each of the libraries needed:

```
g++ bulletTest.cpp -o bulletTest -lGL -lGLU -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision -lBulletSoftBody -lLinearMath -I /usr/local/include/bullet/
```

In addition, I had to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

and then it would both compile and run.